# UITableView and UITableViewCell did not update after NSUserDefaults change

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, cells

Im doing an app that allows the user change the background color and the font of the UITableViewCells on the main viewcontroller of the app. As you may guess this change is set on the settings page of the app, when i navigate back from the settings page back to the main view, the change did not take place. For example if the background of the table view cells is blue, and i change it to red it will only take place if i kill the app on multitasking and restore it or if i scroll the table view.

I dont now what to do really this is my code, any suggestion would be very appreciated.

```
   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return CoreDatos.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MensajeUsuario", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    let mensaje = CoreDatos[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = mensaje.valueForKey("name") as? String
    cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.toDoItem = mensaje
    return cell
}


 func colorForIndex(index: Int) -> UIColor {

    var ud: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var eleccion: Int = ud.integerForKey("Color")
    let itemCount = CoreDatos.count - 1
    let val = (CGFloat(index) / CGFloat(itemCount)) * 0.6
    var esquema = UIColor()


        switch eleccion
        { case 1 : esquema = UIColor(red: val , green: 0.2 , blue: 0.9 , alpha: 1.0)//HeadApp
          case 2 : esquema = UIColor(red: 0.0 , green: val , blue: 1.0 , alpha: 1.0)//Blue
          case 3 : esquema = UIColor(red: 1.0 , green: val , blue: val , alpha: 1.0)//Red
          case 4 : esquema = UIColor(red: val , green: 0.75 , blue: 0.0 , alpha: 1.0)//Green
          case 5 : esquema = UIColor(red: 0.8 , green: val , blue: 0.75 , alpha: 1.0)//Pink
          case 6 : esquema = UIColor(red: 0.5 , green: val , blue: 1.0 , alpha: 1.0)//Violeta
          case 7 : esquema = UIColor(red: 0.9 , green: 0.9 , blue: 0.9 , alpha: 1.0)//White
          default : esquema = UIColor(red: val , green: 0.2 , blue: 0.9 , alpha: 1.0)//HeadApp

        }


    return esquema  }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell:     UITableViewCell,
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = colorForIndex(indexPath.row)
}
```

The former are the methods for the table view, in the color for index i use NSUserDefaults in order to read the user choice.

I don't now what method to call to reload the view in order to see the changes.

At this point i really don't now what to do, any help please i really really appreciate it.

Comment: The method `[tableview reloadData]` generally and `[tv reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:];` specially are used to reload data at particular row.

Comment: In swift you have to use self.YourTableName.reloadData().

Comment: Thank you both but that was the first aproach that I took, i've also tried needsetdisplay and several others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

in

```
viewDidAppear
```

Reason your tableview is not updating is that it is in the same state you set in viewDidLoad. After changing your settings, it still remained the same as viewDidLoad is not called again when navigating back from settings. Although viewDidAppear will be called when navigating back from settings.

> if i kill the app on multitasking and restore it or if i scroll the
>   table view.

Killing the app will call viewDidLoad again & load latest values.
Scrolling will also load latest data in cell because

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

will be called & load updated values.